# is there a way to input user text through rich text editor like quill and POST the data as a .json file

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular9

I have a rich text editor called ngx-quill which takes user input and
I need to create a JSON file with the user input and post the JSON file.

I need to know how to create the JSON file with the user input

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use Quill.js - Your Powerful Rich Text Editor for my project in laravel.

But, since quill uses:

```
<div id="editor"></div> || <div id="editor" name="body"></div>
```

Instead of a reqular old:

```
<textarea id="editor" name="body"></textarea>

$post->body = $request->input('body');
```

won't work.

What do I use to save the information I get from a div with the id of #editor into a database.

Thanks

https://mauiketotreats.com/